# RPi - Multiple Buttons with same ground pin

Tags: button, gpio

I need to get input from multiple buttons (10 buttons), when pressed it should return 1 and when its not pressed it should return 0.
The problem now is that it works with the first button, the second stays 0.

If I change from Ground pin to the 5v pin, only the second one reacts and returns 0 when pressed and 1 when its not.

What can I do to get a signal from EVERY button, not just one?

Comment: Its depends on you r button first. If you are using normal buttons which does not require extra power to the button then its easy.

Answer (score 1):

Its depends on what type of button you are using, I assume you are using the buttons which does not require extra voltage from any sources.

So, If you are using normal buttons, you need to connect ground, you need to pass 3V because raspberry GPIOs operating on 3.3V. (you can use 5V to make that button working). 
 Let me post how I am doing.

I have connected my buttons with GPIOs, Ground (First dropping ground to breadboard and using from breadboard) and 3.3V
When press the button it gives me the value 1 and when release the button that gives me the value 0.
I am using **PIGPIO** and running `PIGPIOD` service to detech GPIOs activities.
See:[pigpio](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/)

**Note:** Just you need to make break connection and close connection when pressing button with ground and 3.3V to give signal to GPIO.
IF you need i can post my code (Python) too.